# Drools validation: Variables can not be used inside bindings

Tags: drools

In Drools, I created a drl file with the following content:

```
import com.myorg.model.Child;
import com.myorg.model.ExportData;
import function com.myorg.utils.getParentSalary;

rule "Classification childSpecialSchool"
when
    $exportData : ExportData(  )
    $child : Child($parentSalary: getParentSalary($exportData, this), $parentSalary > 4000, _age < 15 && _age > 10)
then
    $child.set_classification("childSpecialSchool");    
end
```

In my Java application, I fill WorkingObjects with a list of children and an exportData containing a lot of information.

```
Collection<Object> objectsForRules;
objectsForRules.addAll(listChildren);
objectsForRules.add(exportData);
```

ExportData is a class with a field mapSalary

```
class ExportData {
   Map<Child, Double> mapSalary;
}
```

When I validate the drl file I have the following error [KBase: defaultKieBase]: Variables can not be used inside bindings. Variable [$exportData] is being used in binding 'getParentSalary($exportData, this)'.

I saw 2 other topics with same error but answers didn't help.

Someone can help? I am using Drools 7.37.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference `$exportData` there.

You could, as a workaround, move the parent salary logic outside of the `Child` reference like this:

```
rule "Classification childSpecialSchool"
when
    $exportData : ExportData(  )
    $child : Child(_age < 15, _age > 10)
    $parentSalary: Integer( this > 4000 ) from getParentSalary($exportData, $child)
then
    $child.set_classification("childSpecialSchool");    
end
```

(I'm assuming that the result of `getParentSalary` is an Integer but you can adjust as needed.)

Comment: It works. Thanks for this answer.
I used a simplified code but finally I want to execute a more complex test with and/or logics.
I want to test "if child age is between 10 and 15 or parent salary is greater than 4000 then set classification to 'childSpecialSchool'"
How could I write it?

Comment: You'd write two rules in that case. One for child age, and one for parent salary.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand the logics.